# How to call a phonegap funcation inside a iframe

Tags: html, iframe, phonegap-build

I want to call a function in my index page which is available at "phone gap file", I have called my index page inside phone gap file with in a frame.
Current code working in web but not in application,Please any one suggest me

```js
//code inside phonegap
function clickImage(){
   alert("Phonegap app");
          
} 

//Code inside normal html


function clickPicture(){
              
              window.parent.clickImage();
                
            }
```

```html
index.html
_______________
<body>  
<button onclick="clickPicture();">Take Picture</button>
  </body>


Phonegap.html
_____________

<iframe  id ="Qusframe" src="index.html" width='100%' scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' >
  <p> Your browser does not support iframes. </p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you please share your directory structure which file is referenced where? like what goes into index.html or phonegap.html, I am looking for .js files.

Comment: If you could please share above i can guide you through two possible ways to resolve your issue.

Comment: you may also refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548677/how-to-access-cordova-functions-from-an-iframe-in-phonegap-ios/29302165#29302165) and seek my answer if that can resolve your issue too.